# In SQL, how to find all rows where ANY column meets a condition?

Tags: sql, dynamic

I want to find the rows in the table where ANY column meets a certain condition.

For example, if I have a table `RobTest`:

```
-- Example Table
create table #RobTest
    (A varchar(10), B varchar(10), C varchar(10))
insert into #RobTest
    select 'Blue', 'Green', 'Green' UNION ALL
    select 'Green', 'Blue', 'Green' UNION ALL
    select 'Green', 'Green', 'Green'
```

If I wanted to find all rows where ANY column has a field with the value `'Blue'`, I could write:

```
select * from #RobTest 
where A = 'Blue' or B = 'Blue' or C = 'Blue'
```

And obtain rows 1 and 2.  But this solution could get unwieldy if the table had dozens of column names or if you can't be sure the column names might change and you are running the query as an audit, for instance.  So how to do this dynamically?

Comment: Or you count write `select * from #RobTest where 'Blue' in (A,B,C,D)`

Comment: Quick comment: If you can check dozens of different columns for the same value, then you probably have normalization issues.

Comment: SQL server, Oracle, DB2, MySQL... syntax and information_Schema vary. but general concept by @MichaelCurrie is reasonable to handle dynamic nature of this request.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to find the column names, then use a cursor to iterate over all columns, using dynamic SQL to populate a temporary table with the rows satisfying the condition.

Following the code above, assuming the `#RobTest` definition given in the question:

```
-- Find all columns of #RobTest
select COLUMN_NAME
INTO #ColumnNames
from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME like '%RobTest%'

-- Create a place to hold our results
select * into #RobTemp from #RobTest
truncate table #RobTemp

-- Set up varaibles for our iteration process
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnCursor CURSOR
DECLARE @currentColumn NVARCHAR(100)
SET @columnCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM #ColumnNames

-- Go through the columns one at a time and then run the query on that column.
OPEN @columnCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @columnCursor INTO @currentColumn
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @sql = 'select * from #RobTest where ' + @currentColumn + ' = ''Blue'''
    insert into #RobTemp
        exec sp_executesql @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM @columnCursor INTO @currentColumn
END

-- Show the results
select * from #RobTemp
```

Comment: #1 you can `select * into #RobTemp from #RobTest where 1 = 2 ` instead of truncating it. 
#2 you should consider building the whole dynamic sql and execute it at once, like this : `set @sql = case when isnull(@sql, '') = '' then 'select * from #RobTest where ' else @sql + ' and ' end + @currentColumn + ' = ''Blue'' '`